# Where can one get Ubuntu-compatible linux-tools package for a new Linux kernel?

Tags: software-installation, kernel, ppa, tools

Various kernel builds for Ubuntu are available at the [Ubuntu Kernel PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). But only the following packages are included for each kernel at the PPA site:

```
linux-headers-{kernel_version}...
linux-image-{kernel_version}...
linux-module-{kernel_version}...
```

I am also in need of the `linux-tools` and `linux-tools-generic` (if possible) packages for a recent stable kernel build (say the most recent as of today, [Kernel 5.1.10 packages at Ubuntu Kenel PPA](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1.10/)) . How do I go about getting that/those package(s)?

Comment: What are wanting to do? I use the mainline kernels almost 100% of the time, although I compile them myself. For some of the tools (turbostat, for example) I have had to bypass the very very over restrictive dependency conditions of the Ubuntu version, by compiling and installing the tool myself.